# How can I delegate an implementation to a mutable property in Kotlin?

Tags: java, delegates, kotlin, delegation

As to my understanding, the idea of delegating an implementation in Kotlin is to avoid code that looks like this:

```kotlin
class MyClass(val delegate : MyInterface) : MyInterface
{
    override fun myAbstractFun1() = delegate.myAbstractFun1()
    override fun myAbstractFun2() = delegate.myAbstractFun2()
    // ...
}
```

Instead, we can write the following code which should do the same:

```kotlin
class MyClass(val delegate : MyInterface) : MyInterface by delegate
```

Now, I'd like `delegate` to be a mutable variable, i.e. my code looks like this:

```kotlin
var delegate : MyInterface = MyImplementation()
object MyObject : MyInterface by delegate
```

So if I'd delegated every abstract method to `delegate` by myself like in the first example, changing the value of `delegate` does change the behaviour of the methods. However, the above code compiles to this Java code:

```java
public final class MyObject implements MyInterface {
    public static final MyObject INSTANCE;
    // $FF: synthetic field
    private final MyInterface $$delegate_0 = MyObjectKt.access$getDelegate$p();

    @NotNull
    public String myAbstractFun1() {
        return this.$$delegate_0.myAbstractFun1();
    }

    @NotNull
    public String myAbstractFun2() {
        return this.$$delegate_0.myAbstractFun2();
    }
}
```

So obviously, instead of just using the `delegate` field, the Kotlin compiler decides to copy it when creating `MyObject` to a final field `$$delegate_0`, which is not modified when I change the value of `delegate`

Is there a better solution for doing this instead of delegating every method manually?

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: @Todd I'm trying to have a global object that holds the configuration of my library as well as providing methods to modify it. I know there are different ways to accomplish this, but this seems like a convenient way to have properties and methods in one place without creating a wrapper class

Comment: It doesn't even work if passing a proper `object`! It seems the compiler really, really want to know statically what's going to happen. I think that makes sense, too; if you implemented the methods yourself, they wouldn't change at runtime (unless reflection), so in order to have similar guarantees, the compiler needs to fix the delegate.

Comment: @Raphael I don't see how that makes sense, as a manually implemented method can change bedaviour when the instance variables change. So why shouldn't that be the case for auto-generated methods as well?

Comment: @msrd0 A manually implemented method depends only on statically known declarations, and the compiler can reason about those (e.g. a `val` won't change). If you swap out the delegate -- potentially with a whole different class! -- what is _declared_ as a `val` (in the delegate interface) suddenly changed. (Note how you could never ever delegate `val`s!) Therefore, if you allowed to swap out delegate objects, the compiler can rely on (far?) fewer things. Now, that doesn't imply one _couldn't_ allow that; it's probably a trade-off.

Comment: I think a discussion about design choices would be better off on https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/.

Comment: See (and vote for it) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-83

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, as far as I know there is no way of changing the delegate by changing the original property content, **but** you might still be able to do something similar by working in an immutable way and copying the object:

```
interface MyInterface {
  fun foo():Int
}

data class MyClass(val delegate : MyInterface) : MyInterface by delegate

object ImplementationA: MyInterface { override fun foo() = 7 }
object ImplementationB: MyInterface { override fun foo() = 5 }

val objA = MyClass(ImplementationA)
println(objA.foo()) // returns 7

val objB = objA.copy(ImplementationB)
println(objB.foo()) // returns 5
println(objA.foo()) // still 7
```

Hope this is still useful.